# Is it possible to interact with a contract deployed within another contract via web3js?

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-design

Be very helpful to know if the scenario below is possible

contract A {
import "./B.sol";

...
address c = new B();
b = B (c)

}

//somewhere in JS
instance_of_B = web3.eth.contract(B.abi).at(c);

Answer (score 3):

Yes its possible.

Web3.js doesnt care how the contract was deployed. It just needs:
 - the contract ABI
 - the contract address
 - and a provider to transport requests to the Ethereum Blockchain

Now, you need to return the address of the new contract created to the outside world, so that web3 can see it. You cant return data from a transaction , however you can use emit an event with the address of the contract and have web3 monitor this event

Answer (score 3):

You have approximately answered your own question. Let's walk through the details and sort out the concerns and syntax.

The requirements for reading a contract are

1. Knowledge of the ABI. That can be derived by compiling source code or just given.
2. Knowledge of the contract address.

Contract design can assist with the second requirement.

You wouldn't do:

```
contract A { import "./B.sol"; ...
```

But, you might do

```
import "./B.sol";

contract A { ...
```

And, you could have a function to deploy a new `B`:

```
function createB() public returns(address contractB) {
  B b = new B(); // cast b as B, defined by "contract B" in the imported file
  return address(b);
}
```

Since that is a state-changing function, software clients will only get a transactionHash and not `address(b)` - that response is only available to other contracts. It can be very useful and is generally recommended to also emit an event for an important state-change such as this. Events are observable by a Web3 watcher.

```
import "./B.sol";

contract A {

  event LogNewB(address creator, address contractB);

  function createB() public returns(address contractB) {
    B b = new B();
    emit LogNewB(msg.sender, b);
    return address(b);
  }
```

What if the observer isn't watching? It can be useful to make this discoverable by inspecting the contract. A can keep track of the B instances it deploys:

```
address[] public bList;
...
bList.push(b);
```

Altogether ...

```
import "./B.sol";

contract A {

  address[] public bList;
  event LogNewB(address creator, address contractB);

  function createB() public returns(address contractB) {
    B b = new B();
    emit LogNewB(msg.sender, b);
    bList.push(address(b));
    return address(b);
  }
```

Since `bList` is `public`, you get a "free" getter that will return the address at a row, roughly equivalent to:

```
function bList(uint row) public view returns(address) {
  return bList[row];
}
```

Now there are three ways for a Web3 client to construct a list of all the B contracts that were deployed by A. They can listen to event logs, resolve mined transaction hashes and inspect the log arguments, or inspect the `bList`. Together with knowledge of ABI for B, the client can:

```
var instanceB = web3.eth.contract(abi).at(address);
```

As Julien pointed out, Web3 is indifferent about the method that was used to deploy the contract.

Hope it helps.

p.s. It may be helpful to add a quick function to reveal the length of the `bList`, otherwise software clients will not know where the end of the array is. Something like:

```
function getBCount() public view returns(uint) { return bList.length; }
```